# Unity container in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a simple question. I'm newer with UnityContainer of Miscrosoft. I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application with Unity for DI.
Have I a different CONTAINER for each user connected to my web app? Or the CONTAINER is the same for all users?
So if I resolve the life time of an object with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager does it mean that only for one user session this object is always the same?

I hope you understand.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: `I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application with Unity for DI.` - Do note that the Unity project is dead. For new applications it would be best to use one of the [many other containers](https://github.com/danielpalme/IocPerformance) that are still active.

Comment: Really? What is the best for .net applications? I need to implement also cross-cutting concern. Autofac?

Answer (score 2):

Lifetime refers to the life of the object created by the DI process.  Per request means each request gets its own object.  If the object depends on the current user, querystring values on that request or values/presence of Request headers a PerRequest lifetime is appropriate.  If you have settings that vary based on location of your service, for example, you saved values from web.config, then a the container is most likely created in global.asa and these objects can live as long as the container lives.

A concrete example:

You have a service as part of your site and you are migrating to vNext of that service.  Users can opt-in by clicking a link that includes a parameter like `&myService=vNext` to see the new behavior.  your Factory method uses the value of this parameter to select vNow or vNext for each request.

Here's some pseudo code to get you started:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IProductFactory>("enterprise", new EnterpriseProductFactory());
container.RegisterInstance<IProductFactory>("retail", new RetailProductFactory());
container.RegisterVersionedServiceFactory<IProductFactorySettings, IProductFactory>();
```

In this example RegisterVersionedServiceFactory is an extension method that does nothing but decide which of the IProductFactory instances to use for the current request.  The factory provides the current instance (there are only two for the life of the service) to use for this request (thousands per seconds).

This pattern is what makes a very large site you probably used recently both very stable and very flexible.  New versions of services are rolled out using this exact same pattern to help keep the site very stable.

Comment: I mean if I resolve with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager  an object for the connection to the database is this object  the same for all clients connected to my wep app?

Comment: The answer is it depends. I think generally it is desirable to share connections so your data base performs better.  totally different conversation. I would have to dig deeper into our code than I did to see but my advice is to just try out the different registration types. Create an object that has a use count, register it multiple ways and ask each thing you get back its use count. If it's always one then you have a factory that creates one per request. If it increases on each reference it's a Singleton.  If the use count unexpected returns to 1 after a period of increasing you have a bug.